# LMS Channel error: Your component must be rendered before you can publish to channel

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-message-service

I have two Aura Components that talk to each other via 2 LMS channels. The flow goes: Once we click on the quick action button on Case Header, it would fire a LMS channel that will be subscribed by one of the open subtabs' Aura component. This subtab aura component publishes another LMS channel which will be subscribed by the quick action component to render some data.

I believe, here the issue comes with the subtab not being loaded (due to API heavy implementation), but quick action readily available for user to click. Meaning, I was able to publish the channel from my quick action, but the subtab is not available to subscribe and fire the onMessage event that publishes another channel yet.

Here is the sample code:

QuickAction.cmp:

```
<aura:attribute name="QAflag" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doneRendering}"/>

<aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.QAflag}">
    <lightning:messageChannel type="QARenderChannel__c" scope="APPLICATION"
        aura:id="qaMessageChannel"/>
</aura:renderIf>
```

QuickAction.js:

```
 doneRendering: function(component, event, helper) {
 const message = {
      details: "QA Clicked"
    }
 component.find("sampleMessageChannel").publish(message);
 component.set("v.QAflag", false);
}
```

SubTabAura.cmp

```
<lightning:messageChannel type="QARenderChannel__c" scope="APPLICATION"
    onMessage="{!c.handleQAChannel}"/>

<lightning:messageChannel type="QADataChannel__c" scope="APPLICATION"
    aura:id = "qaDataChannel"/>
```

SubTabAura.js:

```
handleQAChannel : function( component, message, helper ){
  const message = {
        type :'recordPage',
        details : {allData:  component.get("v.allQAData")
                  }
    }
 component.find("qaDataChannel").publish(message);
},
```